# java operation on Files - java.io.File or cmd commands

Tags: java, file, cmd

i need to perform some operations on files  - rename, delete and etc.

what is better? use cmd commands or use java.io.File methods?

thanks.

Comment: This depends for what you need that :)

Comment: What you want perform and after perform what would you do with results?

Comment: is there any scenario that it is better to use cmd commands? lets assume i just want to rename a file or delete a file and then go on with other things. in the case, is it better to use cmd command? and another scenario is that i want to rename a file and then read it.. here i assume that using File.io is better. am i right? are there other scenarios?

Comment: Sorry but I can't catch what you wan't to ask. Sorry but your question is like "what is better elephant or lion?". Cmd line is quite different of java. Java is language which needs compilations, cmd is just tool of windows which allows to work with system, also it has own script language (known as bat files).

Comment: ok, my bad. i'll explain better. i'm writing a java program. my java program needs to do some operations on files. within the java code i can do it via File.io or i can do it via cmd. my question is a general question regarding executing cmd commands at runtime or using java File library for that. what is better, why? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it's not a good idea to depend on OS specific things in a platform independent environment, not mentioning the speed which would be much slower with the local commands.

I would stick with the Java implementations, if it's possible with them.

Comment: why is it slower to use local commands than  java implementations?

Comment: because Java has to fork an another process to run your command.

Comment: I guess unless you're issueing those commands on thousands of files the impact is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of comments I catch the real question. So my answer is:

Of course it is better to use java feauters, because:

1. If you wan't your program to be portable you can't use command line, because it wouldn't work on unix or other systems expect windows. Also can't work on some other versions of windows.
2. To use command line feautures from your code you should creat new process end execute this commands, which is very slow.